# Read last 20 bytes from a file

Tags: c, io

```
int fd, read_byte;
char *c;  

fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY);

read_byte = read(fd, c, 20);

printf("");
```

How to read last 20 bytes from a file and print the read_byte to the screen.

Comment: Why open and not fopen?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`lseek(2)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?lseek%202)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, read_byte;
    char c[21];

    fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // reposition fd to position `-20` from the end of file.
    lseek(fd, -20L, SEEK_END);  
    read_byte = read(fd, c, 20); // Read 20 bytes
    c[read_byte] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", c);

    close(fd);

    return 0; 
}
```